# Reporting Services HTML export - image resizing issue

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, html-rendering

Hello.

In order to execute reports’ rendering into the HTML 4.0 format I use the ReportExecutionService class

In order to get exported report as a stream I use the following code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(connection.Render(format, dev_info, out ext, out mime_type, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds));
```

The issue is: when I display the received stream in a browser, the images with the “Fit proportional” property display incorrectly.

The original SSRS reportViewer and my project the images display as in the picture below:

[image 1](http://i55.tinypic.com/2w3djqq.jpg)

Image properties in the Designer:

[image 2](http://i55.tinypic.com/1y4kk3.png)

What configuration settings should I set so that I am able to display exported report with images from my application as in the original SSRS reportViewer?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the best way to include images in reports is to pre-size the images to the actual size you want them displayed in the report and then set to use "Original Size".
Using "Fit Proportional" often seems to result in poor image quality when the image is resized, it could also be causing the issue you are seeing as well.